# How to find 'local network share' folders?

Tags: file-sharing

On Ubuntu 14.04LTS, I have shared a folder using the GUI "local network share" interface.  It's working fine, and I can access the share from Windows machines on my LAN.

My question is how to find which folders on the Ubuntu system which are shared?  (If, for example you've forgotten where the shared folder was.  Or if you want to get a list of such shared folders.)

According to multiple articles on the web, this information should be in an smb.conf file somewhere, but sharing the folder thru the GUI does not seem to modify any such file.  I've found 3 smb.conf files on the system (/usr/share/samba/smb.conf, /etc/samba/smb.conf, /run/samba/upgrades/smb.conf) but all of them are in the original pristine unmodified state and do not have any references to the folder shared via Nautilis.

I give up: where is the configuration information for these shares stored??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

Despite all of the misinformation out on the web which says that shares are configured in smb.conf, it turns out that when you creat a "local network share" in nautilis, it creates a file in **/var/lib/samba/usershares** It looks like one flat ASCII file per share.  The file name is the same as the share name, and it contains the local path, the "comment" that remote users see, and the access control parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of all of your shared paths with the following command

```
cat /var/lib/samba/usershares/* | grep path
```